# X over SSH with Xming - Qt Qml application

Tags: windows, qt, ssh, xserver

I'm trying to make an X-Session over SSH with [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/) and Putty. This works fine with every application, that is Software-Rendered (e.g. A Qt5-Application). When I'm now trying to do this with my Qml-Application an egl error (3003) appears.

In my virtual machine (Virtualbox -> Host: Windows 8, Guest: Debian 64Bit) X over SSH runs like expected. Probably I have to install another driver for Win8/7 (tested both) to enable Hardware Acceleration (OpenGL / EGL).

Comment: That's not QML limitation. It is based on Open GL which has poor support for remote visualization. If you have a commercial license you can consider  the [Qt Quick 2D Renderer](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2015/01/22/introducing-the-qt-quick-2d-renderer/) or fallback to [ANGLE](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt-5-on-Windows-ANGLE-and-OpenGL).

Comment: Sadly I'm not using a commercial license. Angle on the other hand forces me to compile my application for windows. That's not what I want to do. I just want to do a "private" remote Session to my embedded Linux device.  Is there no other way, to achieve this?

Comment: No one that I know of. Can't you cross compile for your device, can you?

Comment: No there's no way. This application runs on industrial machinery and the X-Session is used for remote support. That way I would have to save every version that I deploy to our customers - that's complicated and too much work.

Comment: I see. Hope someone else would provide you a viable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out, that the [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/index.html) X11 server works with OpenGL / QML. This way I can make a X over SSH Session on windows.

Comment: Good to know! That is a really useful information for everyone interested in the topic. Thanks for sharing.